# Scale animation jumps?

Tags: css

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7urbffw/)

On hover I wish to scale anything in the a tag, including an image.

I use:

```
a:hover{
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

And this works, but then when the animation ends, the image snaps back to it's original size. I need it to stay large until the hover goes out.

Please note I cannot apply the animation to the image itself because I also need to animate whatever is inside the a tag.

Comment: I have closed it as a dupe because even though the actual transforms are different, the root cause is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `display:inline-block` to your `<a>` tag seems to fix this.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/u7urbffw/1/)